# Move a SVN repository

Tags: svn

In a previous place I worked with a SVN repository, more than 500 code revisions. Now I got out of job and created a new fresh SVN repo. I wanted to "move" all the content of the old to the new SVN repo. What I did was to checkout, and then import into the new one, but as far as I can see, only the last version of the code is available at the new repo. What could I do in order to "move" it completely?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options.

**Dump** command:

```
svnadmin dump /path/repository > RepositoryName.dmp

cd /path/NewRepository
svnadmin create NewRepositoryName
svnadmin load NewRepositoryName< RepositoryName.dmp
```

Another option is to use the **hotcopy** command

`svnadmin hotcopy SourceRepositoryPath NewRepositoryPath`

After that, you need to relocate your working copy to the new repository. To do that, use the **switch** command.

Answer (score 1):

You need to take svn dump and then populate the new repo with it.
[Read through](http://whynotwiki.com/Subversion_/_Dump_and_loading)

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using svnsnyc. One advantage is you don't need to have admin access to the old repository. You just need to execute two commands:

init:
http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svnsync.c.init.html

sync:
http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svnsync.c.sync.html